# How do you access pngs from different directories and merge them?

Tags: python, image, merge, directory, png

I can't find a way around merging multiple pngs if they're not in the same directory as main.py.
I'd use:

```py
from PIL import Image

#myFolder has layer1.png, layer2.png, myFolder is in same directory as main.py
Image.alpha_composite(-,-).save("test1.png")
```

to merge the pngs together.

Comment: How would you merge them if they *were* in the same dir?  What stops you using a path to outside the main dir?

Comment: If they were in the same dir, I'd do `Image.alpha_composite("layer1.png","layer2.png").save("test1.png")`, and my lack of experience is what's holding me back, I'm quite the newbie.

Comment: What package does `Image` come from?

Comment: Are you using hard coded paths or do you want to select some from the file system?

Comment: @tdelaney cv2? (guess)

Comment: @2e0byo - or PIL or image, or... who knows! biscuitbreaker needs to give us more details.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and put your code in there, not unformatted in the comments. Thank you.

Comment: You can't composite images by filename, you need `im1=Image.open(FILENAME)` then composite `im1`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yep, that did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Python has several modules that can build path names. `pathlib` is a good choice. Python scripts and modules include a magic variable `__file__` that names the file being executed. You can use that to find the script's directory and then `pathlib` to get the path to `myFolder` and its contents. `Path` overrides the division operator to join path names. Clever... if not a bit too clever. After that, you need to open the two images to get the composite.

```
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

# get this script's directory and then png directory underneath
script_folder = Path(__file__).absolute().parent
my_folder = script_folder/"myFolder"

Image.alpha_composite(Image.open(my_folder/"layer1.png"), 
    Image.open(my_folder/"layer2.png")).save("test1.png")
```